# Timeout trying to fetch resolutions from npx-force-resolutions

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I am trying to force resolve certain dependencies using below command

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

After every attempt it throws a timeout error and breaks out.

Stacktrace:

`Error: Timeout trying to fetch resolutions from npm at switch__2144__auto__ (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\13732\node_modules\npm-force-resolutions\out\npm_force_resolutions\core.cljs:61:3)`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to 0.0.3 version of npm-force-resolutions seems to have fixed the issue. I did try timeout in .npmrc, didn't quite helped.

Run `npx npm-force-resolutions@0.0.3`

or if you had this in your scripts section of package.json then update as below:

`"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions@0.0.3"`

References: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

Just got this problem. Setting longer time works in my side. And I didn't downgrade.

`npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 1000000`

You might try to set longer time, if still timeout. It takes longer time I expected...